# Define a "base Url" in a Retrofit Interface

Tags: java, retrofit2

I created a Java library for a REST service using Retrofit (https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

I have an Interface which looks like this:

```
public interface OrganizationUnitsApi {

    @GET("organizationUnits")
    Call<List<OrganizationUnit>> getOrganizationUnits();

    @GET("organizationUnits/{organizationUnitId}")
    Call<OrganizationUnit> getOrganizationUnit(@Path("organizationUnitId") String organizationUnitId);
}
```

As you can see, both times I resolve to the endpoint "organizationUnits", so my requests in the end will be sent to "https://myservice.com/organizationUnits..."

Is there a possibility in Retrofit to like "annotate" a base Url for this Interface?
Maybe something like this?

```
@Path("organizationUnits")
public interface OrganizationUnitsApi {

    @GET("/")
    Call<List<OrganizationUnit>> getOrganizationUnits();

    @GET("{organizationUnitId}")
    Call<OrganizationUnit> getOrganizationUnit(@Path("organizationUnitId") String organizationUnitId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such API at this moment in retrofit similar to what you are exactly trying to do. However, if you must need to do that, you can pass the `organizationUnits` as part of the [baseUrl](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html) while building the retorfit object.

So now you are doing something like this

```
Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(someUrl)
```

You can instead do something like the following

```
Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(someUrl/organizationUnitId)
```

But in that case, if you are using the same base url for multiple API interface, you will have to do extra hassle to configure those separately.

Comment: Hmm I figured as much... But still thank you for the clear up 